# SMS application in PHP

Tags: php

I wish to build a sms application in php from scratch.

Please guide me how to develop the product from start to end.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your question is like: "Tell me how to program." I'm sure you don't mean it this way. - The question is too broad and maybe you can ask a question that is more to the point. Alternatively find a tutorial on PHP then work through that. Increasingly you will be able to attack increasingly difficult challenges. (PS: I didn't down vote your question.)

Comment: -1 and voting to close as not a real question. You are not outlining any detail about what your application is supposed to do. In what countries it is supposed to work. etc etc

Comment: I wish to build an application like 160 by2.com in php can anyone guide me now please

Comment: @Ankur you clearly have no interest in asking a real question.

Comment: this is a question way over your head. this is like asking how to build an ebay-like application without giving us an idea what your skills are.

Comment: I want to write a website that is like facebook.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need a sms-gateway or build one yourself (using your cellphone, etc.).
This article gives some examples about an existing (low-cost) sms-gateway and how to send messages thru HTTP: http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Sending-SMS-Thru-HTTP/